# Accessing notes to encrypt in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, encryption

I am creating an iPhone platform version of an encryption tool. I need to access notes that users save to encrypt. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Yes I know, I never realized you could have a dash between two words in tagging *facepalm*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iOS application sandbox doesn’t allow you to do this—your app doesn’t get access to other apps’ data except via system APIs like EventKit. If you want users to be able to store encryptable notes, your app will have to either allow them to write those notes inside it in the first place or sync with a service like [Simplenote](http://simplenoteapp.com/).